# PHP Include another php that queries MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, include, require

In my site im trying to include on the top of each page a "banner" that is itself a separate php page that queries a MySQL database to return a number that displays.

When i goto the exact URL of the banner php url (www.sitename.com/banner.php) it works perfectly.

However, when i include the banner into another page include'banner.php' it returns the following error: *Database access error 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)*

I have 2 ways i need to include this, my main site pages are all php. My forum is phpbb and the file i need to include is HTML so i used  (Note, i did ../ back out to the banners root, its not a matter of my file not being found.

Im assuming that when including the scope is different. How would i correctly accomplish this include?

Banner.php

```
<?php
require("../mysql.inc.php");
check_get($tp, "tp");
$tp = intval($tp);
$link = sql_connect();
$result = sql_query($link, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM online_count");
if (!$result) {
  echo "Database error.<br>\n";
  exit;
}
list($total) = mysql_fetch_row($result);
mysql_free_result($result);
?>  
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menu_css.css" media="screen"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="menucenter">
<div class="Online"> <? echo"$total" ?> Online</div>
</body>
</html>
```

mysql.inc.php

```
<?php

$SQLhost = "****.db.****.hostedresource.com";
$SQLport = "3306";
$SQLuser = "****";
$SQLpass = "****";
$SQLdb   = "****";


function sql_connect()
{
global $SQLhost, $SQLport, $SQLdb, $SQLuser, $SQLpass;

if ($SQLport != "")
$link = @mysql_connect("$SQLhost:$SQLport","$SQLuser","$SQLpass");
else
$link = @mysql_connect("$SQLhost","$SQLuser","$SQLpass");
if (!$link) {
echo "Database access error ".mysql_errno().": ".mysql_error()."\n";
die();
}
$result = mysql_select_db("$SQLdb");
if (!$result) {
echo "Error ".mysql_errno($link)." selecting database '$SQLdb': ".mysql_error($link)."\n";
die();
  }
return $link;
}

function sql_query($link, $query)
{
global $SQLhost, $SQLport, $SQLdb, $SQLuser, $SQLpass;

$result = mysql_query("$query", $link);
if (!$result) {
echo "Error ".mysql_errno($link).": ".mysql_error($link)."\n";
die();
}
return $result;
}

function check_get(&$store, $val)
{
$magic = get_magic_quotes_gpc();
if (isset($_POST["$val"])) {
if ($magic)
$store = stripslashes($_POST["$val"]);
else
$store = $_POST["$val"];
}
else if (isset($_GET["$val"])) {
if ($magic)
$store = stripslashes($_GET["$val"]);
else
$store = $_GET["$val"];
}
}

?>
```

Comment: What is your database connection code? The function sql_connect().

Comment: Have you tried following the path to see if the socket file actually resides there? Additionally, is the sql_connect function native? I can't find any documentation on it.

Answer (score 0):

@Craig, there is a possibility that the include file contains other includes which are not getting the right path. Can you paste some codes of the include file for us to validate the error ?

EDIT:
You have a missing quote at the end of the query.

```
$result = sql_query($link, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM online_count);
```

It should be

```
$result = sql_query($link, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM online_count");
```

EDIT:
You have a problem with the quotes. See you check_get function. $val is a variable and you dont need quotes around it. Check the below code.

```
if (isset($_POST[$val])) {
if ($magic)
$store = stripslashes($_POST[$val]);
else
$store = $_POST[$val];
}
else if (isset($_GET[$val])) {
if ($magic)
$store = stripslashes($_GET[$val]);
else
$store = $_GET[$val];
}
```

EDIT:
Also remove the quotes from $query:

```
$result = mysql_query($query, $link);
```

Comment: I edited my first post to show the php code of the include file

Comment: Well, one of quick error i found is the missing " after your sql query. $result = sql_query($link, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM online_count"); Check your query after online_count. The " is missing.

Comment: That was already there, for some odd reason it removed it here ;P

Comment: Accepted. You are having some problem with the mysql.inc.php file. Can you paste the code of that as well ?

Comment: Added to original post. It connects to the MySQL server and returns the value fine if i go directly to mysite.com/banner.php

Answer (score 0):

First things first:

1. Remove the @ from your mysql statements and see if you are getting any other errors related to variables or so. You should not suppress errors while debugging.
2. Try printing the host, port, user and password variables inside the sql_connect() function and see if you are getting the correct values in your function.
3. If you have access to your server, check if /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock exists, and has sufficient permissions.

   srwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql 0 Sep 21 05:50 /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

If all is well till this point, you might want to troubleshoot your MySQL service further. A restart would help flush the connections, if that is the issue. Check a similar thread in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452222/mysql-connect-returning-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-on) too.